# outlook 2010 <li> styles and <br> are ignored

Tags: html, outlook, html-email

Having a problem with HTML resolving in Outlook 2010.

There should be an equal space between each `<li>` I have sucesfully done this with the UL style applied inline as you can see below of `line-height:2;` .

However this disrupted an `<li>` with multiple lines -- making it look strange because the `<li>` with multiple lines should online be `line-height:1;` so you can tell it's the same `<li>` but in Outlook 2010 the below resolves with `<li>` #2 following the first `<li>` being immediately below the first `<li>` **with no space**.

As you can see I am trying `padding-top:5px;` inline I have also tried `padding-bottom:` on the top element, I have also tried `<br>` and `</br>` and border-`bottom:3px solid #fff;` and I cannot create this break space correctly between these `<li>`'s nothing resolves in Outlook 2010. I'm about to try a white image, but would rather not, any suggestions?

```
<ul style="line-height: 2;">
  <li style="line-height:1;border-bottom:2px solid #fff;">lorim impsum ipsum lorim impsum ipsum<br>
    lorim impsum ipsum
</li>
  <li><span style="padding-top:5px;display:block;">lorim impsum ipsumlorim impsum ipsum</span></li>
```

---

Basically the above resolves like:

```
• lorim impsum ipsum lorim impsum ipsum
  lorim impsum ipsum 
• lorim impsum ipsum lorim impsum ipsum
```

**and it needs to be:** *(in Outlook, Gmail and Web it's fine)*

```
• lorim impsum ipsum lorim impsum ipsum
  lorim impsum ipsum 

• lorim impsum ipsum lorim impsum ipsum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook removes styles in li tags, and one of those is padding.  Use this guide for more info on CSS accepted in different email clients - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

The alternative would be to use a table with tds using the `&bull;` in the left td and the copy on the right, like below:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td style="line-height:1;border-bottom:2px solid #fff;">&bull;</td>
<td>lorim impsum ipsum lorim impsum ipsum<br>
    lorim impsum ipsum
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>&bull;</td>
<td><span style="padding-top:5px;display:block;">lorim impsum ipsumlorim impsum ipsum</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to replace `<br>` by `<div>&nbsp;</div>` it works for me.

I also see that Outllok works correctly if you put `<br></br>`in this case it renders 3 lines but it breaks other modern email clients, they will render 6 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have given up on using `<li>` for bulleted lists in my emails. Too many finicky issues with MS Outlook. Here is what I have found to work best.

I use a CSS tag to push the left margin to the right a bit (20px, in this example), then use "text-indent" to pull the first line back (-15px, in this example)

I also use the numeric character reference ID for the bullet (`&#8226;`)

```
p.bullet {
    margin: 10px 0px 20px 20px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}

<p class="bullet">&#8226;&ensp;List item 1.</p>
<p class="bullet">&#8226;&ensp;List item 2.</p>
```

I have had no issues with it rendering correctly in MS Outlook, or other mobile email apps.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it. I've added pre-style in the header.

```
pre {
        white-space: pre-line !important;
        font-family: your-font !important;
    }
<pre>Your text. \n Your second line text.</pre>
```